# why kafka current offset reduces

Tags: apache-kafka

I regularly check the status of multiple kafka calling `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` (once per minute).
Typically, sum of **current offset** is growing steadily.

Very rarely (maybe 5 out of 100), sum of "current offset" is reduced. In such cases, I get negative processing speed. The formula:

> speed = (sum of "current offset" (current) minus sum of "current
>   offset" (previous)) devided by seconds

passed. Could you tell why **current offset** can be reduced.

Sample kafka-consumer-groups.sh output:

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --new-consumer --bootstrap-server g81:9092 --group fGroup -describe

GROUP, TOPIC, PARTITION, CURRENT OFFSET, LOG END OFFSET, LAG, OWNER
fGroup, mOutput, 1, 87665473, 87665473, 0, null-0de00d94-dbbf-4593-8e4e-26e305524be7_10.1.0.11/10.1.0.11
fGroup, mOutput, 7, 87665191, 87665191, 0, null-947c0e97-92ac-471d-a3e0-a059a952b289_10.1.0.11/10.1.0.11
fGroup, mOutput, 3, 87665015, 87665015, 0, null-45684fef-19c6-46ed-b7b4-16127089f88d_10.1.0.11/10.1.0.11
fGroup, mOutput, 5, 87665205, 87665205, 0, null-6fb529e0-59f0-4bc5-9651-a9195d769a09_10.1.0.11/10.1.0.11
fGroup, mOutput, 2, 87665402, 87665402, 0, null-440a96ff-98ea-4cfb-b2f6-1cf05966b2f7_10.1.0.11/10.1.0.11
fGroup, mOutput, 6, 87665239, 87665239, 0, null-89b3ce22-092e-437a-b87b-0b2e38e18806_10.1.0.11/10.1.0.11
fGroup, mOutput, 9, 87665750, 87665750, 0, null-f1cb1482-7e01-40ee-a658-bccd8c8572ac_10.1.0.11/10.1.0.11
fGroup, mOutput, 8, 87665130, 87665130, 0, null-c7a6763c-2547-4121-9051-1ff718afbd47_10.1.0.11/10.1.0.11
fGroup, mOutput, 0, 87665391, 87665391, 0, null-04cd35a1-e6cd-475a-8af4-035b2af8088a_10.1.0.11/10.1.0.11
fGroup, mOutput, 4, 87665233, 87665233, 0, null-64f1dd24-7c78-49d4-aa3a-fab4b34bd213_10.1.0.11/10.1.0.11
```

Comment: This can happen if a consumer uses `seek()` to go back to re-read some older data.